# Actionscript 3 - Passing one variable from one object to another in the same project

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, variables

I'm fairly new at ActionScript 3 but I am working on it and trying to learn by reading and modifying ActionScript source codes.

So far so good, however I stumbled upon one problem which I seemingly can't solve by myself. It should be faily simple for you guys tho.

The situation:

I got one "object" which is clickable and gives a random value which is also being saved in a variable.
I got another "object" which does the same thing but only has a different name. 
I want the variable from the first object to be passed to the second one, how can I do it?

Comment: Can you post some code for us to understand?

With the limited information given - the first object is clickable, so you can have eventlisteners. Get the other object to listen to that and grab the data?

Comment: Do you basically speaking want both objects to share that value and allow either one to set it to a new value?

Comment: I added the source codes now ;)

Answer (score 0):

One way to pass values relies on using references to objects...

```
// mc1 and mc2 exist as movieclips on the stage

mc1.addEventListener( MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick );
mc2.addEventListener( MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick );

function onClick( event:MouseEvent ):void
{
    // reference clicked movieclip through click target
    var mc:MovieClip = event.target as MovieClip;

    // if our clip matches one, assign the other clip the value.
    if ( mc === mc1 )
    {
        mc2.value = mc.value;
    }
    else if ( mc === mc2 )
    {
        mc1.value = mc.value;
    }
}
```

There's a thousand ways to pass references around, and this is just one.

Answer (score 0):

OK guys let me show you the important parts of the code (cant show it all since I paid for it and I don't know whether the author woudl be OK with me publishing all of it).

I got these two objects there. When I click on one of the objects (which is a DICE), it gives me this code basically

```
var faceValue:int = 6;

// Add mouse click functionality to roll the die
addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClickDie, false, 0, true);
mouseChildren = false;
buttonMode = true;

function onClickDie(e:MouseEvent):void {
    removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClickDie);
    buttonMode = false;

    // Initiate the roll-out sequence
    if(faceValue == 6) {
        gotoAndPlay("rollout6");
         etc...
```

Then somewhere in the frame where it is SPINNING the dice it is randomizing a number and save it into facevalue

```
// Calculate a random face value between 1 and 6
faceValue = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random()*6);

// Initiate the roll-in sequence
if(faceValue == 6) {
    gotoAndPlay("rollin6");
    ...etc
```

Now how can I get the randomized facevalue from the spinning the dice frame to pass it to the other dice?